# Spring with MongoTemplate: java.lang.String com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.getDescription()

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I am trying to create a simple application that handles MongoDB database with MongoTemplate. However, this method:

```
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), this.mongodbName);
        return template;
    }
```

fails with this exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/myapp/tryout/repository/config/MongoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.getDescription()'
```

pom.xml has these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring version is 5.2.6.
Documentation of this com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings tells that the method in question is indeed deprecated. Moreover by looking in ClusterSettings class I cannot find this method.

My question is: Is it about mismatch in current releases of Spring and mongo-java-driver? If yes, can you please point out a correct combination of packages to use?

Please ask, if you need more information. I will gladly provide it.

ADDED: Ah, irony...
I found this

```
    private static Cluster createCluster(final MongoClientSettings settings,
                                         @Nullable final MongoDriverInformation mongoDriverInformation) {
        notNull("settings", settings);
        List<MongoCredential> credentialList = settings.getCredential() != null ? singletonList(settings.getCredential())
                : Collections.<MongoCredential>emptyList();
        return new DefaultClusterFactory().createCluster(settings.getClusterSettings(), settings.getServerSettings(),
                settings.getConnectionPoolSettings(), getStreamFactory(settings, false), getStreamFactory(settings, true), credentialList,
                getCommandListener(settings.getCommandListeners()), settings.getApplicationName(), mongoDriverInformation,
                settings.getCompressorList());
    }
```

in com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.

And this

```
    public Cluster createCluster(final ClusterSettings clusterSettings, final ServerSettings serverSettings,
                                 final ConnectionPoolSettings connectionPoolSettings, final StreamFactory streamFactory,
                                 final StreamFactory heartbeatStreamFactory, final List<MongoCredential> credentialList,
                                 final CommandListener commandListener, final String applicationName,
                                 final MongoDriverInformation mongoDriverInformation,
                                 final List<MongoCompressor> compressorList) {

        ClusterId clusterId = new ClusterId(clusterSettings.getDescription());
```

in com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory, which is deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring 3.x supports mongodb java version 4.x. The mongo-java-driver and mongodb-driver “uber-jars” are no longer published as noted in the linked page. Between 3.x and 4.x mongo driver java version the uber jar dependencies have been split to core and sync/reactive streams dependencies. I was able to reproduce the issue with 3.x version. Once I updated to correct 4.x dependencies issue disappeared.

So the correct dependencies are in the below order

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/upgrading/#upgrading-from-the-3-12-java-driver
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#upgrading.2-3

Comment: Bounty is yours in 19h as stackoverflow rules stand

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was correct about versions mismatch.
Changing versions of the mentioned packages to these ones:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

will workaround the issue. I cannot mark this post as an answer to the issue. Seems like version 3.0.* of spring-data-mongodb is not compatible with the latest mongo-java-driver or vice versa. I can be wrong.